# Aggregating table() over multiple columns in R without a "by" breakdown

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a 2-column data frame of x- and y-coordinates of points. I want to generate a table of the number of occurrences of each point. Using the `table()` command produces a table for all possible x-y pairs. I can eliminate the extras with

```
fullTable <- table(coords)
smalLTable <- subset(fullTable, fullTable > 0)
```

And then I'm sure I could do a little something with `dimnames(fullTable)` to get the appropriate coordinates, but is there a better way? Something built in? Something that with

```
coords <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), y = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))
```

would return

```
x y count
1 1 2
2 1 1
2 2 1
3 1 2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using just Vanilla R, you can do

```
aggregate(rep(1, nrow(coords)), by = list(x = coords$x, y = coords$y), sum)
```

Comment: `coords` is a data.frame (which is already a list), so a slightly shorter solution would be: `aggregate(coords$x, by=coords, length)`.

Answer (score 8):

Better than ddply is `count`:

```
library(plyr)
count(coords)
```

It's a lot faster than table for sparse 2d results too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ddply` from the `plyr` library

```
plyr::ddply(coords, .(x, y), summarize, count = length(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(coords)
DT[,.N,by=list(x,y)]
##   x y N
## 1: 1 1 2
## 2: 2 2 1
## 3: 2 1 1
## 4: 3 1 2
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208946) for more details on the use of `.N` and creating frequency tables with `data.table`

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
count(coords, x, y)
```

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(coords)
coords[, .(n = .N), by = .(x, y)]
```