# Simple frequency tables using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking for a way to do simple aggregates / counts via data.table.

Consider the iris data, which has 50 observations per species.  To count the observations per species I have to summaries over a column other than species, for example "Sepal.Length".

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(iris)
dt[,length(Sepal.Length), Species]
```

I find this confusing because it looks like I'm doing something on Sepal.Length at first glance, when really it's only Species that matters.

This is what I would prefer to say, but I don't get valid output:

```
dt[,length(Species), Species]
```

### Correct input and output, but clunky code:

```
> dt[,length(Sepal.Length), Species]
Species V1
1:     setosa 50
2: versicolor 50
3:  virginica 50
```

### Incorrect input and output, but nicer code:

```
> dt[,length(Species), Species]
Species V1
1:     setosa  1
2: versicolor  1
3:  virginica  1
```

#### Is there an elegant way around this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`data.table` has a couple of symbols that can be used within the `j` expression. Notably

- `.N` will give you the number of number of rows in each group.

see `?data.table` under the details for `by`

> Advanced: When grouping by `by` or by i, symbols .SD, .BY and .N may be used in the j expression, defined as follows.
>
> ....
>
> .N is an integer, length 1, containing the number of rows in the group.

For example:

```
dt[, .N ,by = Species]

     Species  N
1:     setosa 50
2: versicolor 50
3:  virginica 50
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine this to also sort by the count (`.N`)? -- Never mind. Found in the help: `DT[,sum(v),x][order(-V1)]`

Comment: @mnel Is there an easy one liner that will give the count and the percentage (or proportion) that that frequency / number / count represents?

Comment: @Farrel does `dt[,.N,by=Species][,prop := N/sum(N)]` suffice?

Comment: @mnel It looks elegant but alas nothing happens. There is no output from your line.

Comment: @mnel That is odd, if I surround the line with print() then it works. How come it does not automatically display?

Comment: @farrel - if you assign it to something it will be there. There is `data.table` magic to stop `:=` automatically printing the results,(from 1.8.4 onwards) - and you have stumbled across the idiomatic approach to force printing (wrapping in `()`)

Answer (score 0):

A more generizable method is

```
dt[, table(col2bCount)%>%as.data.frame, by= .(col1,col2,col3,...)]
```

The key advantage is that columns `col2bCount` and `col1,2,3` can be different(or the same), meaning you can caculate the frequency in one column grouped by a different column(s).