# data.table of table is very different from data.frame of table

Tags: r, data.table

I know that `table` is [not the preferred way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208980/2596586)  to make a frequency table as a `data.table`. But suppose I have a `table`, for whatever reason, that I want to convert to a `data.table`. The `data.table` conversion does not work the same way the `data.frame` conversion does:

```
library(data.table)
tab <- table(1:101)
DF.tab <- data.frame(tab)
DT.tab <- data.table(tab)
```

`data.frame` converts the `table` data into a `data.frame`, while `data.table` attempts to store the original `table` object as a column. (I've tested this with `tab <- table(1:n)` for multiple values of `n`, among other examples.)

```
> str(DF.tab)
'data.frame':   101 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: Factor w/ 101 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Freq: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> str(DT.tab)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  101 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ tab: 'table' int [1:101(1d)] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Note also that while `as.data.frame` works the same way as `data.frame`, `as.data.table` fails entirely:

```
> as.data.table(tab)
Error in UseMethod("as.data.table") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.data.table' applied to an object of class "table"
```

In what seems to be a very closely related problem, if the table is sufficiently large (informal testing suggests `.Dim > 100`), I get very strange errors when trying to `print`:

```
> print(data.table(table(1:101)))
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  dims [product 5] do not match the length of object [10]
```

Note that `print(data.table(table(1:100)))` does not have an error, but only displays one column `V1`, while `print(data.frame(table(1:100)))` has `Var1` and `Freq` columns.

**Is there any better workaround than `data.table(data.frame(...))`? Am I better off always trying to avoid `table` entirely?** And is the `print` error directly caused by this, or is it something deeper?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with pretty printing (how `data.table` prints the top 5 and bottom 5 rows when the total rows are > 100)...

Comment: I think the problem lies in the way `R`makes frequency tables as an array where each unique variable gets it's own dimension, and that unique variable is stored as a `name`.

Comment: you should submit a feature request and a bug report

Comment: Submitted bug report as [#4847](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4847&group_id=240&atid=975) and feature request as [#4848](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4848&group_id=240&atid=978).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an `as.data.frame.table` function that is called with `data.frame(tbl-object)`. It converts the matrix-like table-object to a long-format data object. There appears to be no as.data.table.table function as yet and arguably there should be and I would agree that it should behave in the same manner as as.data.frame method rather than inheriting from matrix (which is how table would usually inherit:

```
> data.table(matrix(1:10, 2))
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  1  3  5  7  9
2:  2  4  6  8 10
> data.table(as.table(matrix(1:10, 2)))
Error in UseMethod("as.data.table") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.data.table' applied to an object of class "table"
> data.table(as.data.frame(as.table(matrix(1:10, 2))))
    Var1 Var2 Freq
 1:    A    A    1
 2:    B    A    2
 3:    A    B    3
 4:    B    B    4
 5:    A    C    5
 6:    B    C    6
 7:    A    D    7
 8:    B    D    8
 9:    A    E    9
10:    B    E   10
```

I think this should be a feature request and I don't think it is related to the second problem.

Your second question seems like a bug. The `data.table` authors most prominently @MatthewDowle are generally quite responsive, and you should consider submitting a report.

Comment: since 2014.there is `as.data.table.table` method available, it will be most likely updated in 2017 in (v1.10.2), or new `array` method will be added.

Comment: Like I said. Matt is an amazing maintainer and Arun a wonderful contributor. Very responsive and interested in making their fork of R an evolving and improving resource.I wasn't aware of these mods and am happy to hear of them. I had tried using `table` within data.table j-calls and been disappointed in the performance.